# Scala Enums - How to assign initial values?

Tags: scala, enums

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
   type WeekDay = Value
   val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
```

How would you set an initial value so `WeekDay.Mon == 1` and `WeekDay.Tue == 2` and so on would be true?

There's a constructor in Enumeration, `Enumeration(initial: Int, names: String*)`, is there a way I could use that to create the WeekDay object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `object WeekDay extends Enumeration(1)` i.e. call Enumeration's constructor.

The second parameter `names: String*` means it accepts any number of string arguments - including none at all, hence just one argument.